# Parent notification within array of objects

Tags: java, class, oop

So, I'm working on a Java program that utilizes a created class (we'll call it "hair").  However, inside this class, you can also have an array of objects which are also objects of class "hair".  So, basically, it looks like this:

- Hair (level 0)

  - Hair (level 1)

    - Hair (level 2)
  - Hair (level 1)

Now, the issue I'm having is this: Let's say, for instance, I change a field in level 2.  I want Level 1 to be notified, but I don't know how to notify level 1. Is there a way I can have an object talk to the object that's containing it?  Now, if I were using Android, maybe I could use a broadcast receiver, but I'm not familiar with anything like this in Java or a way just DIRECTLY talk to the "parent" hair level.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For an object to talk to the parent then it must know about it's parent. For example:

```
class Hair{
  Hair parent;
  public Hair(Hair _parent){
    parent = _parent;
  }
  public void notify(String data){
    ... do what you need to do
  }
  public void changeHair(...){
    ...
    if(parent != null) {
      parent.notify(...);
    }
  }
```

If you need more let me know.

Edit: notify up or down the the object stack but not in both directions as this can and will cause problems without code to handle not notifying the notifier.